# how can I use an array with a class using a dot operator

Tags: c#, arrays, class

using System;

> I am using string[] talentSlots = new string[2];
>   and I want to do a agent.talentSlots = blah blah thing how do I do it?

```
namespace warhammerRPGCB
{
    public class classes
    {
        string className;
        int stanceRed;
        int standGreen;
        string carrerSkills;
        string primaryChar;
        string[] talentSlots = new string[2];
        int focusSlot;
        int reputationSlot;
        int tacticSlot;

        public classes()
        {
            classes agent = new classes();
            agent.className = "Agent";
            agent.carrerSkills = "Charm, Education, Folklore, Guile, Intution";
            agent.stanceRed = 2;
            agent.standGreen = 2;
            agent.primaryChar = "Intelligence, Felloship";
            agent.tacticSlot = focusTalent, reputationTalent;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use an array initializer

```
agent.talentSlots = new string[] {focusTalent,reputationTalent};
```

Comment: Note that the array type can be inferred: `agent.talentSlots = new [] { focusTalent, reputationTalent }`